# Nodejs failed to subtract number

Tags: javascript, math, julia, division, subtraction

I tried to do this calculation with Node.js.

```
let x = 841251657
console.log((x*x)-x)
```

I got: `707704349563994000` printed.

When I use julia I get `707704350405245649` for the same calculation.
And I got `7.0770435e+17` for google calculator.

Apparently, something going wrong here.
What can I do to get the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum safe integer is defined as `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is (2^53) -1, which is the largest integer you can represent with double-precision floating point.

```
> console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
9007199254740991
```

The number you're calculating is significantly larger than that, so precision is being lost.  You can check this with `Number.isSafeInteger((x*x)-x)`.

For numbers this big, you should be using a BigInt library.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using node > v10.4.0, you have BigInt.

```js
let x = 841251657n
console.log(x*x-x)
```

x is a bigint if you append an 'n' as shown above